# How to read input from the keyboard in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, textinput

Hi I am making a program that gets input from the keyboard and I was wondering if there was any way to get input from the keyboard and store it in an `NSString` object.

Comment: What kind of program? Presumably not a traditional GUI, since the fields handle their own input. A console app? Or something with keyboard shortcuts for tools, a la Photoshop? A game?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are doing this as a command-line app, then here's code I wrote last week to get a line from the command prompt (I made it an `NSString` category):

```
+ (NSString *) stringFromStandardInDelimitedByCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)delimiters {
 NSMutableString * string = [NSMutableString string];
 unichar input = '\0';
 while (input = getchar()) {
  if ([delimiters characterIsMember:input]) { break; }
  [string appendFormat:@"%C", input];
 }
 return string;
}
```

And then I'd use it like this:

```
NSString * input = [NSString stringFromStandardInDelimitedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

It doesn't handle unicode characters very well (despite using a unichar), because getchar() only returns a regular char.  However, for basic command-line text entry, it works pretty well.  However, be warned that this will block the thread on which it's executed (since getchar() is a blocking call).

Comment: Why objective-c doesn't came with a native statement like scans in c?

Answer (score 3):

```
- (id)init {
    if( !(self = [super init]) ){
        return nil;
    }
    void (^monitorHandler)(NSEvent *);
    monitorHandler = ^(NSEvent *theEvent){
        switch ([theEvent keyCode]) {
            case 123:    // Left arrow
                NSLog(@"Left behind.");
                break;
            case 124:    // Right arrow
                NSLog(@"Right as always!");
                break;
            case 125:    // Down arrow
                NSLog(@"Downward is Heavenward");
                break;
            case 126:    // Up arrow
                NSLog(@"Up, up, and away!");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
    // Creates an object we do not own, but must keep track
    // of so that it can be "removed" when we're done 
    [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSKeyDownMask) handler:monitorHandler];
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not this?

```
NSFileHandle *kbd = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput];
NSData *inputData = [kbd availableData];
NSString *option = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:inputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```